# TypeError: string indices must be integers with JSON

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get a dictionary that is inside of a script tag on a website. The dictionary is under the var product. I've successfully seperated the dictionary so that it's on its own, however I'm getting the string indices error when I try to use the json. My code is shown below:

```
r = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
s = str(soup.find('script', type='text/javascript'))
data = json.loads(s.split('var product = ')[1].split('</script>')[0].split('new Shopify.OptionSelectors(')[0].split(',"images')[0] + '}')
print(data)
```

this returns:

```
{'id': 1940337819721, 'title': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON', 'handle': 'react-runner-mid-wr-ispa-black-white-anthracite-totalcrimson', 'description': '<span style="color: #ff0000;"><span style="color: #ff0000;">\ufeff</span></span><meta charset="utf-8"><style type="text/css"><!--\ntd {border:1px solid #ccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}\n--></style><span style="color: #ff0000;"><span data-sheets-value=\'{"1":2,"2":"This Launch Product is Final Sale. No refunds, exchanges or cancellations"}\' data-sheets-userformat=\'{"2":6723,"3":{"1":0},"4":[null,2,16777215],"9":0,"12":0,"14":[null,2,16711680],"15":"Arial"}\'>This Launch Product is Final Sale. No refunds, exchanges or cancellations</span></span>', 'published_at': '2018-12-12T05:00:00-08:00', 'created_at': '2018-11-28T13:35:00-08:00', 'vendor': 'NIKE', 'type': 'MENS FOOTWEAR', 'tags': ['18DEC', 'AT3143-001', 'block_ic', 'footwear', 'high', 'men', 'mens-footwear', 'new', 'nike', 'size_10', 'size_10-5', 'size_11', 'size_11-5', 'size_12', 'size_13', 'size_4', 'size_4-5', 'size_5', 'size_5-5', 'size_6', 'size_6-5', 'size_7', 'size_7-5', 'size_8', 'size_8-5', 'size_9', 'size_9-5', 'touch'], 'price': 17000, 'price_min': 17000, 'price_max': 17000, 'available': True, 'price_varies': False, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'compare_at_price_min': 17000, 'compare_at_price_max': 17000, 'compare_at_price_varies': False, 'variants': [{'id': 17953124646985, 'title': '- / 4', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '4', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---4', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 4', 'public_title': '- / 4', 'options': ['-', '4'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 33, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953124679753, 'title': '- / 4.5', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '4.5', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---4.5', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 4.5', 'public_title': '- / 4.5', 'options': ['-', '4.5'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 33, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953124712521, 'title': '- / 5', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '5', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---5', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 5', 'public_title': '- / 5', 'options': ['-', '5'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 33, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953124745289, 'title': '- / 5.5','option1': '-', 'option2': '5.5', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---5.5', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True,'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 5.5', 'public_title': '- / 5.5', 'options': ['-', '5.5'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0,'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 33, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953124778057, 'title': '- / 6', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '6', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---6', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available':True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 6', 'public_title': '- / 6', 'options': ['-', '6'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0,'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 33, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953124810825, 'title': '- / 6.5', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '6.5', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---6.5', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 6.5', 'public_title': '- / 6.5', 'options': ['-', '6.5'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 33, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953124843593, 'title': '- / 7', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '7', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---7', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 7', 'public_title': '- / 7', 'options': ['-', '7'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 33, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953124876361, 'title': '- / 7.5', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '7.5', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---7.5', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 7.5', 'public_title': '- / 7.5', 'options': ['-', '7.5'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 32, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id':17953124909129, 'title': '- / 8', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '8', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---8', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 8', 'public_title': '- / 8', 'options': ['-', '8'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 25, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id':17953124941897, 'title': '- / 8.5', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '8.5', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---8.5', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 8.5', 'public_title': '- / 8.5', 'options': ['-', '8.5'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 17, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953124974665, 'title': '- / 9', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '9', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---9', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 9', 'public_title': '- / 9', 'options': ['-', '9'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 35, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953125007433, 'title': '- / 9.5', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '9.5', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---9.5', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 9.5', 'public_title': '- / 9.5', 'options': ['-', '9.5'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 36, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953125040201, 'title': '- / 10', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '10', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---10', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 10', 'public_title': '- / 10', 'options': ['-', '10'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 82, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953125072969, 'title': '- / 10.5', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '10.5', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---10.5', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 10.5', 'public_title': '- / 10.5', 'options': ['-', '10.5'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 35, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953125105737, 'title': '- / 11', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '11', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---11', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 11', 'public_title': '- / 11', 'options': ['-', '11'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 35, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953125138505, 'title': '- / 11.5', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '11.5', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---11.5', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON- - / 11.5', 'public_title': '- / 11.5', 'options': ['-', '11.5'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 25, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953125171273, 'title': '- / 12', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '12', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---12', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 12', 'public_title': '- / 12', 'options': ['-', '12'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 10, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}, {'id': 17953125204041, 'title': '- / 13', 'option1': '-', 'option2': '13', 'option3': None, 'sku': 'AT3143-001---13', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': True, 'name': 'REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK/WHITE/ANTHRACITE/TOTALCRIMSON - - / 13', 'public_title': '- / 13', 'options': ['-', '13'], 'price': 17000, 'weight': 0, 'compare_at_price': 17000, 'inventory_quantity': 25, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}]}
```

I've tried putting this in a json validator and it's not valid, so I took off json.loads on the data variable:

```
data = s.split('var product = ')[1].split('</script>')[0].split('new Shopify.OptionSelectors(')[0].split(',"images')[0] + '}'
```

which returns a valid format of the json:

```
{"id":1940337819721,"title":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON","handle":"react-runner-mid-wr-ispa-black-white-anthracite-totalcrimson","description":"\u003cspan style=\"color: #ff0000;\"\u003e\u003cspan style=\"color: #ff0000;\"\u003e\u003c\/span\u003e\u003c\/span\u003e\u003cmeta charset=\"utf-8\"\u003e\u003cstyle type=\"text\/css\"\u003e\u003c!--\ntd {border: 1px solid #ccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}\n--\u003e\u003c\/style\u003e\u003cspan style=\"color: #ff0000;\"\u003e\u003cspan data-sheets-value='{\"1\":2,\"2\":\"This Launch Product is Final Sale. No refunds, exchanges or cancellations\"}' data-sheets-userformat='{\"2\":6723,\"3\":{\"1\":0},\"4\":[null,2,16777215],\"9\":0,\"12\":0,\"14\":[null,2,16711680],\"15\":\"Arial\"}'\u003eThis Launch Product is Final Sale. No refunds, exchanges or cancellations\u003c\/span\u003e\u003c\/span\u003e","published_at":"2018-12-12T05:00:00-08:00","created_at":"2018-11-28T13:35:00-08:00","vendor":"NIKE","type":"MENS FOOTWEAR","tags":["18DEC","AT3143-001","block_ic","footwear","high","men","mens-footwear","new","nike","size_10","size_10-5","size_11","size_11-5","size_12","size_13","size_4","size_4-5","size_5","size_5-5","size_6","size_6-5","size_7","size_7-5","size_8","size_8-5","size_9","size_9-5","touch"],"price":17000,"price_min":17000,"price_max":17000,"available":true,"price_varies":false,"compare_at_price":17000,"compare_at_price_min":17000,"compare_at_price_max":17000,"compare_at_price_varies":false,"variants":[{"id":17953124646985,"title":"- \/ 4","option1":"-","option2":"4","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---4","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 4","public_title":"- \/ 4","options":["-","4"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":33,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953124679753,"title":"- \/ 4.5","option1":"-","option2":"4.5","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---4.5","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 4.5","public_title":"- \/ 4.5","options":["-","4.5"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":33,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953124712521,"title":"- \/ 5","option1":"-","option2":"5","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---5","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 5","public_title":"- \/ 5","options":["-","5"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":33,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953124745289,"title":"- \/ 5.5","option1":"-","option2":"5.5","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---5.5","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA -BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 5.5","public_title":"- \/ 5.5","options":["-","5.5"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":33,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953124778057,"title":"- \/ 6","option1":"-","option2":"6","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---6","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 6","public_title":"- \/ 6","options":["-","6"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":33,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953124810825,"title":"- \/ 6.5","option1":"-","option2":"6.5","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---6.5","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 6.5","public_title":"- \/ 6.5","options":["-","6.5"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":33,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953124843593,"title":"- \/ 7","option1":"-","option2":"7","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---7","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 7","public_title":"- \/ 7","options":["-","7"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":33,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953124876361,"title":"- \/ 7.5","option1":"-","option2":"7.5","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---7.5","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 7.5","public_title":"- \/ 7.5","options":["-","7.5"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":32,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953124909129,"title":"- \/ 8","option1":"-","option2":"8","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---8","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 8","public_title":"- \/ 8","options":["-","8"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":25,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953124941897,"title":"- \/ 8.5","option1":"-","option2":"8.5","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---8.5","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 8.5","public_title":"- \/ 8.5","options":["-","8.5"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":17,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953124974665,"title":"- \/ 9","option1":"-","option2":"9","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---9","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 9","public_title":"- \/ 9","options":["-","9"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":35,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953125007433,"title":"- \/ 9.5","option1":"-","option2":"9.5","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---9.5","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 9.5","public_title":"- \/ 9.5","options":["-","9.5"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":36,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953125040201,"title":"- \/ 10","option1":"-","option2":"10","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---10","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 10","public_title":"- \/ 10","options":["-","10"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":82,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953125072969,"title":"- \/ 10.5","option1":"-","option2":"10.5","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---10.5","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 10.5","public_title":"- \/ 10.5","options":["-","10.5"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":35,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953125105737,"title":"- \/ 11","option1":"-","option2":"11","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---11","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 11","public_title":"- \/ 11","options":["-","11"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":35,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953125138505,"title":"- \/ 11.5","option1":"-","option2":"11.5","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---11.5","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 11.5","public_title":"- \/ 11.5","options":["-","11.5"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":25,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953125171273,"title":"- \/ 12","option1":"-","option2":"12","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---12","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 12","public_title":"- \/ 12","options":["-","12"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":10,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17953125204041,"title":"- \/ 13","option1":"-","option2":"13","option3":null,"sku":"AT3143-001---13","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"REACT RUNNER MID WR ISPA - BLACK\/WHITE\/ANTHRACITE\/TOTALCRIMSON - - \/ 13","public_title":"- \/ 13","options":["-","13"],"price":17000,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":17000,"inventory_quantity":25,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null}]}
```

however I'm still getting the same error when I try to call for example

```
data['variants']
```

any idea what the issue is?

Comment: `data` is a list (because that's what `split()` returns). You must use integer numbers to access list items.

Comment: is there anyway to make it not a list? @DYZ whenever I try to access through integer, I just get a key error.

Comment: your `json.loads` version is ok, the reason why it's not a valid json is it's a python dict, if you really want a json, you can use `json.dumps(data)` to check it.

Comment: ok so why am I still getting the error when I use json.loads? @XiaoTan

Comment: It shouldn't get the error if `data` variable is really written like your question.

Comment: you can copy the first return in your question, and just let `data = your_copy`, then `data['variants']`, it works

Comment: wow thank you so much, it worked! Never knew copying it would actually make a difference. @XiaoTan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can copy the first return in your question, and just let data = your_copy, then data['variants'], it works – Xiao Tan

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `data` dictionary is that it includes values which aren't valid Python.  For example, you have `"available":true,`.  Python sees this and looks for a variable named `true`, not the Boolean, `True` (capital 'T').  The same sort of thing goes for `false` and `null`.

One hack you could use is just make variables with those names.  Then `data['variants']` should work.

```
true = True
false = False
null = None
```